# How to add a custom item to a specific WordPress menu item position

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a primary menu registered and displayed that consists of 4 links (home, about, news, blog). I want to add html (a logo) in between the second and third menu and I was wondering if this was possible.

Here is a diagram:
HOME | About | Logo | News | Blog

I was looking at the hook wp_nav_menu_items but I can only add a custom item to either the first position or last.

Before I used jQuery to add html but since the DOM has to be fully loaded the logo loads last and I'm trying to get the logo to show first or at the same time with the content of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PHP Version

One way would be to create 2 navigation menu's which are then used.

header_menu_1 | LOGO | header_menu_2

Within the back-end, you'd need to create a new header location and then add the 2 menu items to it.

Then within your `header.php` file, have this code.

```
<?php
    $args1 = array( 'menu' => 'header_menu_1' );
    $args2 = array( 'menu' => 'header_menu_2' );
    wp_nav_menu($args1);
?>

<img src="LOGO SOURCE" />

<?php
    wp_nav_menu($args2);
?>
```

That will be the easiest way without using jQuery or messing about with plugins.

[WP Nav Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

[Adding New WordPress Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

### jQuery Version

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        if(i == 2) {
            $(this).after('<img src="http://www.socialtalent.co/images/blog-content/so-logo.png" width="250" />');
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bt4w7/)

### CSS Version

This is a really dirty hack way of doing it.

Using nth-child, select out the 2nd and 3rd elements. Both items get more margin for the middle so 2nd element 30px margin right and 3rd element 30px margin left.

Then put the div with the logo in it to be position absolutely in the middle.

Example:

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 1.25%;
    margin: 1.25%;
    background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right:10%;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#container img {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -7.5%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bt4w7/1/)

Comment: Yes I was thinking about doing that but my client wants to just have one menu to manage. I just have no idea where to start. Do I have to work with the walker class?

Comment: Would it be alright to try it in jQuery? ill see if i can quickly knock something together if so.

Comment: Right now I am using jQuery to add html markup after the second item. Again because the DOM has to be loaded first the logo ends up getting loaded last and I need it to load first or with the content. Unless there is way to tell jQuery to immediately add markup at the right time before the DOM finishes loading.

Comment: Im not too sure why the logo loading last matters too much. it will be a just a couple of ms difference to the content unless you have a very very content filled web page. Ive added the jquery i used into my answer just cause.

Comment: After everything is loaded the logo pops in between those menu. I'm currently using this code: '$('.nav li:eq(2)').after("<li class='logo-desktop-container'><a class='brand logo logo-desktop' title='Delectable paleo recipes to eat &amp; feel great' href='/'>Against All Grain</a></li>");' You can see on this site: [againstallgrain](http://againstallgrain.com/)

Comment: Whats the problem in doing it within jQuery then? Im not sure i fully understand why the logo needs to load first. whereas everything else cant. Thinking about it. you could do it within css as a very dirty hacky way. Ill give a quick explanation in the answer above but its really late here and ill get back to it tomorrow for the code.

Comment: The client doesn't like how the logo, along with the slider (which will be next to fix) just suddenly pops up after everything else is loaded. Someone suggested the load order needs to be fixed. Thank you for your help thus far! Will talk to client to see if just making 2 separate menus will suffice.

Comment: Hey wayne. Have a look at the edit i've made to include the `css/html` version. it makes a bigger gap in the middle using `CSS` `nth-child` and then you can position the logo into the middle. shouldn't be too difficult to refactor into wordpress with a couple of `css` class name changes

Comment: I ended up going with the html/css method. Thanks a lot Stewartside!

Answer (score 21):

I solved similar problem this way:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_custom_in_menu', 10, 2);

function add_custom_in_menu( $items, $args ) 
{
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) // only for primary menu
    {
        $items_array = array();
        while ( false !== ( $item_pos = strpos ( $items, '<li', 3 ) ) )
        {
            $items_array[] = substr($items, 0, $item_pos);
            $items = substr($items, $item_pos);
        }
        $items_array[] = $items;
        array_splice($items_array, 2, 0, '<li>custom HTML here</li>'); // insert custom item after 2nd one

        $items = implode('', $items_array);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Please notice, it works only for single-level menu.

Comment: I haven't tried this method yet as the css method suggested by Stewartside is fine for my project. nonetheless this still could be a good reference for other people.

Answer (score 5):

Little variation on Compass' solution, getting rid of the loop.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_custom_in_menu', 10, 2);

// add in Logo in the middle of the menu
//
function add_custom_in_menu( $items, $args )
{
    if( $args->theme_location == 'footer_navigation' )
    {
        $new_item       = array( '<li class="menu-logo"><a href="/"><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a></li>' );
        $items          = preg_replace( '/<\/li>\s<li/', '</li>,<li',  $items );

        $array_items    = explode( ',', $items );
        array_splice( $array_items, 2, 0, $new_item ); // splice in at position 3
        $items          = implode( '', $array_items );
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Not sure if it will be much fast using build in functions. Your choice

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_admin_link($items, $args){
    if( $args->menu_id == 'header_menu' ){
        $items .= '<li class="nav-item">Paste the text or code here</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_admin_link',20,2);
```

Comment: Define this function inside your functions.php file of WordPress