# Horizontal Navigation with Logo in Middle

Tags: css, wordpress, image, navigation

I am creating a website on Wordpress and I would like to have a horizontal navigation menu in my header with the logo in the center as a link to the homepage. I have been able to create this look using the Wordpress menu, but when I look at the website on my phone the "home" link is situated in the center, which isn't how I would like it to be ordered.

Using the current template (HTML) is there a way to finagle the CSS so the nav menu looks similar to these guys: http://bostonscally.com?

Thanks!

```
#mpcth_page_header_content #mpcth_logo_wrap #mpcth_logo {
display:none;
}

#mpcth_page_header_content {
text-align: center;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#mpcth_menu {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-flex;
}

#mpcth_menu .menu-item-166 > a {
  position: relative;
background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Bostin-Irish-Header_Woo.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
text-indent: -9000px;
padding: 0px;
}

#mpcth_page_header_content #mpcth_controls_wrap {
padding-right: 2em;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can u post your code please?

Comment: If you could add the header code too so we can see the HTML. ive put in an answer which gives a good overview and also a previous question that is very much related which should help you.

Comment: their menu has the home button twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently answered a question similar to this.

It can be found here: [How to add a custom item to a specific WordPress menu item position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622607/how-to-add-a-custom-item-to-a-specific-wordpress-menu-item-position/22622831#22622831)

There are 3 options as i said in the answer above.

jQuery, PHP or HTML/CSS and its down to what you are most comfortable with and if it is for a client, what they most prefer.

I would personally go with the PHP way and split the navigation in 2 and have the logo in the middle.

## EDIT

So you'll need the jQuery version.

Your navigation will need to be setup with Home being the first element on the navigation. This will mean that the mobile version will have home as the first link.

Next you need to add the jQuery below underneath your inclusion of the jQuery library

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("ul#mpcth_menu").find("li:contains('Home')").hide(); // hides home from navigation
    var position = jQuery("ul#mpcth_menu li").length-1;
    var i = 0;
    jQuery('ul#mpcth_menu li').each(function() {
        if(i == position/2) {
            jQuery(this).after('<img src="http://www.bostonirishclothing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Bostin-Irish-Header_Woo.png" width="250" />');
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

This code removes the first element from the main nav, being the Home button, then figures out how many is left and places the logo into the middle.

You will also need to remove the CSS which adds the logo to the class menu-item-166 as this may cause problems.

Hope this fixes your problems.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tes4h/1/)

Comment: My clients are tech savy enough that they should be able to update their own website, but they do not have the ability or know how to make CSS/HTML changes. Ideally, I would like them to be able to add/remove nav items without having to make any changes to the CSS or HTML.You can see the header/nav here: bostonirishclothing.com. Is there specific code you are looking for in the header.php file? As mentioned before I am using a purchased theme and there is a LOT of code to pick from.

Comment: Right, best option would be a jQuery version which loads in loads in the logo to the center point. Ill quickly make a demo with the code and be back with you within the next 5/10 mins

Comment: @user3478950 see the amended answer. should solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I am new to JQuery and implementing it with Wordpress so I actually have no idea where I am actually suppose to put that code. I was thinking of doing some tinkering on the site, but I did not want to put the code somewhere that will crash the site. Any chance you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sure. The best place to put it would be in the `header.php` file and put it right above the closing head tag (`</head>`). This means that jQuery gets initialized way before. Make sure to put it in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags so the page see's it as JavaScript. It wont break the actual functions of the website if it does crash. It runs after the web page has loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've created a child theme and put in the code in a new header.php, but the changes aren't happening. I've looked at both codes and everything looks right.

Comment: Looks like jQuery isn't using the normal `$` indicator and instead is falling back to `jQuery`. see my amended answer

Comment: That fix did the job! Thank you very much!

Comment: I've applied my CSS to the header and now everything is vertically aligned in the middle as the client wants it. But I am hesitant to use a flex box since Safari does not support the code without additional coding. Is there any JQuery code that can be used to get the same look I have on the site without using CSS: display: inline-flex?
http://bostonirishclothing.com

Comment: What do you mean about the flex-box? I dont know where your getting the flex box stuff from? If it has nothing to do with the navigation then I think you'll need to accept + close this question and open a new one with the full details of what your asking.