# Make a Responsive Javascript Horizontal Navigation with Logo in Center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, navbar

I found a [question/post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796523/horizontal-navigation-with-logo-in-middle) on this site that works great upon first looking at it, until I need it to do more, and I have played with it and have not found a solution yet as to get it to do what I need it to do.

I am building a site for a client so I need it to be easy to operate in terms of if the client wants to change the actual order of things, so building a ul/li list on the back end within the theme is not an option, unless there is an easy way for me to modify the functions.php and change the way the menu tab is set up.

Here is my javascript coding, the menu is an actual wordpress menu.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items").find("li:contains('Home')").hide(); // hides home from navigation
    var position = jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items li").length-1;
    var i = 0;

    jQuery('ul#menu-primary-items li').each(function() {
        if(i == position/2) {
            jQuery(this).after('the img src code is in here');
        }

        i++;
    });
});
```

On full page width I need it to look like

```
Link | Link | Link | LOGO IMG | Link | Link |Link
```

On media width (the themes @media max-width is 999px) I need it to be a drop down style wordpress box with

```
LOGO IMG
WP "MENU" button
Link
Link
Link
Link
Link
Link
```

Instead of it displaying as the above, it shows as

```
WP "MENU" button
Link
Link
Link
LOGO IMG
Link
Link
Link
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check media in JQuery code, to set LOGO position:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items").find("li:contains('Home')").hide(); // hides home from navigation
    var position = jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items li").length-1;
    var i = 0;

/* check media here */
var isMedia999=false;
isMedia999 = (window.width() < 1000); //true if max width is <=999px
/* chek is done */

if( ! isMedia999)
    jQuery('ul#menu-primary-items li').each(function() {
        if(i == position/2) {
            jQuery(this).after('the img src code is in here');
        }
        i++;
    });

else jQuery('ul#menu-primary-items li').each(function() {
        if(i == 0) { // <== first position if max width 999px
            jQuery(this).after('the img src code is in here');
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

Of course this wont be actualized.refreshed on resize, so you could do:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         myfunc();
         windows.resize(myfunc());           

    });

    function myfunc(){
 jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items").find("li:contains('Home')").hide(); 

                var position = jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items li").length-1;
                var i = 0;

            /* check media here */
            var isMedia999=false;
            isMedia999 = (window.width() < 1000); //true if max width is <=999px
            /* chek is done */

            if( ! isMedia999)
                jQuery('ul#menu-primary-items li').each(function() {
                    if(i == position/2) {
                        jQuery(this).after('the img src code is in here');
                    }
                    i++;
                });

            else jQuery('ul#menu-primary-items li').each(function() {
                    if(i == 0) { // <== first position if max width 999px
                        jQuery(this).after('the img src code is in here');
                    }
                    i++;
                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: where would `windows.resize(){ ...refresh here... }` go?  and is it supposed to just say "refresh here"

Comment: @CamilleRa'Chelle i edit my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite better: Use CSS and 2 logos.

1 logo is hidden for a media width > 999px, the 2nd is hidden for media <= 999px width.

```
@media max-width is 999px {
 .logo#wide { display:none; }
 .logo#tiny { display:inline; }
}
@media min-width is 1000px {
 .logo#wide { display:inline; }
 .logo#tiny { display:none; }
}
```

**EDIT**: JQuery :
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items").find("li:contains('Home')").hide(); // hides home from navigation

```
 var position = jQuery("ul#menu-primary-items li").length-1;
    var i = 0;

    jQuery('ul#menu-primary-items li').each(function() {
        if(i ==  0) {
           //put logo tiny here for media maxwidth 999px
        }
        if(i == position/2) {
          //  put logo wide here for media minwidth 1000px
        }

        i++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Does something like this could work ?

```
@media(max-width:whateveryouwant px)
{
   .logo{
   float:right;
   }
}
```

An other approach would be to move the element threw the DOM.
You can achieve this with jQuery :

```
if((window).width() <= sizeYouWant){
   $('.logo').insertBefore('#FirstElement');
}
```

Comment: Thank you @baldráni, that did not work exactly but it did help remove it from the smaller screen sizes in the menu.   I had to change it to `@media(max-width:whateveryouwant px)
   .logo{
   display: none;
   }`   in the logo class, floating it hides the image but moves two of the links from the center to the left of the screen, display none helped in keeping everything centered but hiding the image.  How do I get the image to appear above the menu on smaller resolutions, should I try it in the css also or is there like an else/if function I need to use to get it to appear?

Comment: Well what you could try is to place a logo on top which is basically `display:none`. You `display:inline` it when you came to `max-width: ...px`

Comment: Hmm... manage this in JQuery, what you think ? I post an answer. SY.