# jQuery: can't replace LI.after with IMG

Tags: jquery

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797307/667903), I attempted to replace the `<LI>Logo</LI>` with an `IMG` on a Wordpress website, see: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nur29p96/).

However, the replacement is not occurring.

Help appreciated.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-header-menu" class="genesis-nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-104"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/" itemprop="url">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-109"><a href="/shop" itemprop="url">Products &amp; Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/blog/" itemprop="url">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-110"><a href="/" itemprop="url">Logo</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/success-stories/" itemprop="url">Success Stories</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-107"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/about/" itemprop="url">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108"><a href="http://vmpersonal.com/contact/" itemprop="url">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("ul#menu-header-menu").find("li:contains('Logo')").hide(); // hides home from navigation
        jQuery("ul#menu-header-menu").find("li:contains('Logo')").after('<img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Logo-1.png" width="124px" />');
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: @user3378165 Thanks, yes, `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. I thought jQuery required a `$` instead of `jQuery` when using Wordpress?

Comment: @Steve  you missed jquery library in your original code

Comment: @Steve In future, please add the error message as part of the original description. There is no way for us to just know about it.

Comment: Directly use html  
        $("ul#menu-header-menu").find("li:contains('Logo')").html('<img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Logo-1.png" width="124px" />');

Comment: @Steve  check the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the jquery library, include it, and it should work.

In general when you enqueue jQuery in Wordpress you must use jQuery, and `$` is not used (this is for compatibility with other libraries).

You will probably have to wrap the script in this function: (As per your comment that you use Wordpress)

```
(function($){

    // jQuery code is in here

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery. Just include a script tag for it in your HTML and you should be fine.