# move custom menu in a particular position

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml, storefront

I displayed WPML language switcher in my menu, at the bottom as the last item. I want it at the second position of the secondary menu.

How to change my code to achieve that please?

Current code:

```
/*Display WPML language switcher in the menu */
function wpml144107($menu, $args){

    if ( ! is_admin() ):
        if( $args->theme_location == 'secondary' ):
            if(function_exists('icl_get_languages')):
                $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=custom');

                if(count($languages) >= 1):

                    $flags = '<li id="menu-item-lang"><div class="flags_top">';
                    //foreach((array)$languages as $language):
                            //echo print_r($languages);
                            $language = $languages['fr'];
                            $flags .= '
                            <span class="icl-'. $language['language_code'] . ( $language['active'] == 1 ? ' icl-current' : '' )  .'">          
                                <a rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $language['language_code'] . '" href="' . $language['url']. '">' . $language['language_code'] . '</a>
                            </span>  /';

                            $language = $languages['en'];
                            $flags .= '
                            <span class="icl-'. $language['language_code'] . ( $language['active'] == 1 ? ' icl-current' : '' )  .'">          
                                <a rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $language['language_code'] . '" href="' . $language['url']. '">' . $language['language_code'] . '</a>
                            </span>';

                    //endforeach;
                    $flags .= '</div></li>';
                endif;

                return $menu . $flags;
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;
    return $menu;
}
add_action('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpml144107', 50, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point:

```
return $menu . $flags;
```

The language menu is appended to the menu.

If you change it to:

```
return $flags . $menu;
```

It would be at the first position...

But you want to have it at the second one, right? Then it is a little more complicated, you have to split the string containing the menu, I suppose that every element is within a `<li>`-element:

```
/* finds the position of the first occurrence of </li>, 
so the end of the first element, add 4 because we want the position of 
the end of the </li>-tag not the start... */
$splitpos = strpos($menu, '</li>') + 4; 

// cut the string up to that position and you get the first element...
$firstelem = substr($menu, 0, $splitpos));

// cut after that position and you get the rest of the menu...
$rest = substr($menu, $splitpos));

// now return the menu with your language menu in between...
return $firstelem . $flags . $rest;
```

I guess this should work! :)

Comment: The answer after mine seems to do the same thing but a little more complicated, the loop is unneassery i think!

I would like to comment on that, but unfortunately I can just comment on my own posts, so if you test my solution and it works pls vote me up... :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do it: I split the menu items in an array to be able to insert your language switcher in 2nd position.

I have revisited your code a bit:

```
// Display WPML language switcher in 2nd position of the menu
function wpml144107($items, $args){

    if ( ! is_admin() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary' && function_exists('icl_get_languages') ):

        $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=custom');

        if( count($languages) == 0 ) return $items; //  If there is no languages we return defaults menu items

        $html = 'id="menu-item-lang">
        <div class="flags_top">
            <span class="icl-'. $languages['fr']['language_code'] . ( $languages['fr']['active'] == 1 ? ' icl-current' : '' )  .'">
                <a rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $languages['fr']['language_code'] . '" href="' . $languages['fr']['url']. '">' . $languages['fr']['language_code'] . '</a>
            </span>  /';

        $html .= '
            <span class="icl-'. $languages['en']['language_code'] . ( $languages['en']['active'] == 1 ? ' icl-current' : '' )  .'">
                <a rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $languages['en']['language_code'] . '" href="' . $languages['en']['url']. '">' . $languages['en']['language_code'] . '</a>
            </span>';

        $html .= '</div>
        ';
        // Html in between each items (to split the items in an array)
        $glue = '</li>
<li ';
        // Spliting menu items in an array
        $items_array = explode( $glue, $items );

        // Counter
        $count = 0;
        foreach($items_array as $key => $item){
            // We insert in 2nd position the language switcher
            if($key == 1)
                $ordered_items[$count] = $html;
            else
                $ordered_items[$count] = $item;
            $count++;
        }
        // We set back the array of menu items in a correct html string
        $items = implode( $glue, $ordered_items );

    endif;

    return $items;
}
add_action('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpml144107', 50, 2);
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Tested and Works in WooCommerce 3+

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945340/2217647)

with this code:

```
/*Display WPML language switcher in the secondary menu at the second position*/
function add_custom_in_menu( $items, $args ) 
{
    if( $args->theme_location == 'secondary' ):
        if(function_exists('icl_get_languages')):
            $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=custom');
            if(count($languages) >= 1):

                $items_array = array();
                while ( false !== ( $item_pos = strpos ( $items, '<li', 3 ) ) )
                {
                    $items_array[] = substr($items, 0, $item_pos);
                    $items = substr($items, $item_pos);
                }
                $items_array[] = $items;

                $customHtml = '<li>bla</li>';
                $flags = '<li id="menu-item-lang"><div class="flags_top">';
                    //foreach((array)$languages as $language):
                        //echo print_r($languages);
                        $language = $languages['fr'];
                        $flags .= '
                        <span class="icl-'. $language['language_code'] . ( $language['active'] == 1 ? ' icl-current' : '' )  .'">          
                            <a rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $language['language_code'] . '" href="' . $language['url']. '">' . $language['language_code'] . '</a>
                        </span>  /';

                        $language = $languages['en'];
                        $flags .= '
                        <span class="icl-'. $language['language_code'] . ( $language['active'] == 1 ? ' icl-current' : '' )  .'">          
                            <a rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $language['language_code'] . '" href="' . $language['url']. '">' . $language['language_code'] . '</a>
                        </span>';

                //endforeach;
                $flags .= '</div></li>';

                // insert custom item after 2nd one
                array_splice($items_array, 1, 0, $flags); 

                $items = implode('', $items_array);

            endif;
        endif;
    endif;
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_custom_in_menu', 10, 2);
```

I think it's the same approach you guys suggested. Thank you.